# how to implement a filter with vec in rust

Tags: rust

I have a vec i64 that store some element with some entity ids. I want to filter some specify entity id and return a new vec. what I am trying to implement this operation like this way in rust(this is a minimal example, the real element was some word Object):

```
fn main() {
    let current_word_id:i64 =1;
    let wordIds:Vec<i64> = Vec::new();;
    let current_sentences: Vec<i64> = wordIds
        .iter()
        .filter(|sen| sen == current_word_id)
        .collect();
}
```

when I compile this code,facing a problem like this:

```
error[E0277]: can't compare `&&i64` with `i64`
  --> src/main.rs:16:27
   |
16 |         .filter(|sen| sen == current_word_id)
   |                           ^^ no implementation for `&&i64 == i64`
   |
   = help: the trait `PartialEq<i64>` is not implemented for `&&i64`

error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<i64>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&i64`
  --> src/main.rs:17:10
   |
17 |         .collect();
   |          ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<i64>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&i64>`
   |
   = help: the trait `FromIterator<&i64>` is not implemented for `Vec<i64>`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0432.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

I am follow the https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244880/filtering-a-vec-of-structs-and-creating-new-vector-of-strings-or-strs-in-rust. why did not work as expect? What should I do to make it work? what is the right way to do some filter with vec in rust?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So... there's a few things here.

When iterating over `Vec`, there are 2 methods you can use - `iter(&self)` and `into_iter(self)`. The first takes a reference to the `Vec` and iterates over that - essentially a view into the `Vec`. The second consumes the `Vec` and iterates over that, destroying it in the process and turning the `Vec` *into* an iterator.

You have used the first, therefore you shall be dealing with references inside the `Vec<i64>` or `&i64`. The filter function should not take the values iterated over because that would mean draining the iterator, so it takes a reference to the elements inside the iterators (in this case `&i64` thus getting a `&&i64`). So fixing the `&&i64 == i64` issue is down to just making sure the types match (ie. `|sen| sen == &&current_word_id` or dereferencing the `sen`).

The second part here is that because you are iterating over `&i64` as we saw before, this is exactly what you would collect. This can be fixed by mapping the items to a dereferenced value. Given that this is also a possibility in the first problem, this mapping can happen before the filter.

Putting it together, it would bring the example down to this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let current_word_id:i64 =1;
    let wordIds:Vec<i64> = Vec::new();
    let current_sentences: Vec<i64> = wordIds
        .iter()
        .map(|v| *v)
        .filter(|sen| sen == &current_word_id)
        .collect();
}
```

Comment: `.map(|v| *v)` is better written as [`.copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) :)

Comment: @liangqicai I must warn you that this only works because `i64` implements `Copy` as it is relatively cheap to copy the underlying value. This would not actually work with owned (and non-copy) types since moving ownership would require different type signatures.

Comment: "in this case &i64 thus getting a &&i64 "
 why get &&i64?

Comment: If you look at the documentation for [filter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter), you will see that the `predicate` argument is a function that takes `&Self::Item`. Seeing that in this case `Self::Item` is the type `&i64`, combining the 2 would make `&(Self::Item)` -> `&(&i64)` -> `&&i64`

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter), you'll see they point out why this is:

> Because the closure passed to filter() takes a reference, and many iterators iterate over references, this leads to a possibly confusing situation, where the type of the closure is a double reference:

You'll want something like this:

```
wordIds.iter().filter(|sen| **sen == current_word_id).collect::<Vec<&i64>>();
```

Comment: why is it a double reference?